# Kotlin Higher Order Function in ViewModel

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to kotlin , so need help to understand the code ,I went to a blogs and found something like this and implemented in my code , code work perfect but i can't understand the following things .

Basically , I got lost in how **lazyDefferd** function , how it's works internally.
a. How generic T is passed .
b. What it mean by this `CoroutineScope.()` as i know this is input that i need to pass from the `ViewModel` but how it's getting pass i can't understand .

```
interface MovieRepository {
    suspend fun getTopRatedMovie(page:Int): LiveData<out List<TopRatedMovieEntity>>
}
```

ViewModel :

```
class TopRatedMovieViewModel(movieRepository: MovieRepository):ViewModel() {

   val topMovie by lazyDefferd{
       movieRepository.getTopRatedMovie(1)
   }

}

fun <T> lazyDefferd(block:suspend CoroutineScope.()->T):Lazy<Deferred<T>>{
    return lazy {
        GlobalScope.async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
             block.invoke(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a. How generic T is passed.

You can pass it explicitly, e.g.:

```
val myLazyDeffered = lazyDefferd<SomeType> {
    // …
}
```

But the compiler can usually infer the type, so it's more usual to omit it (unless there's a reason why it's not clear from the code).  That's what's happening in your `topMovie` example: the compiler knows what type the lambda returns, so it infers `T` from that.

(As you've probably already noted, `lazyDefferd()` also takes a value parameter, but since it's the last parameter and a lambda, Kotlin lets you omit the parens.)

> b. What it mean by this `CoroutineScope.()`

That's a [function literal with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver).  The lambda that you pass to `block` will behave as if it's an extension method on the `CoroutineScope` class: inside the lambda, `this` will refer to a `CoroutineScope` instance.  It's similar to passing the instance as a parameter to the lambda (and in this case, that's how it's called), but the syntax is more concise.